# How to find the value of c that makes this PDF valid?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Trying to figure out this stats problem, but I'm feeling stuck on it:

*The PDF for a continuous random variable X is the following:*

$f(x)$ = $\dfrac{c}{x^4}$ if $x>2$ and $0$ otherwise.

*What is the value of $c$ that makes this PDF valid?*

It hints that $\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{-a} = 0$ for any constant $a>0$.

I'm not quite sure how to interpret this hint or how to solve the problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The hint is probably to draw attention to the fact that a certain improper integral associated with the PDF is convergent (though it does so poorly). What properties does a PDF normally have? One of those is the key to figuring out what the right value of $c$ is. By the way, you should put some part of your question in the title of your post to make it easier for people to notice.

Answer (score 3):

To be a PDF, we need that the integral over its domain is equal to 1. So $$\int_2^\infty \frac c{x^4} \, dx =1$$ from which you can integrate and solve for c.

Comment: Wow, didn't realize it was that simple. Thanks for the help! It makes sense now!